# How to apply comma to a number with decimal in php

Tags: php

In my program i want a number convert to money format for example i have values $a, $b adding those numbers final result should be display money format means add with ,(comma for above thousand values) and decimal value

```
$a = 1095362.2362548;

$b =155482.94974120325;

$result = $a + $b;

echo $result;
```

the answer is 1250845.18599600325 but i want result should be like 12,50,845.18  i try like

```
echo number_format($result,2,'.',',');
```

but the result is 1,250,845.18 it is also not correct how can i do it

Comment: Can you please explain how `12,50,845.18` would work as an expected output? Why would you want 1 `,` to be 3 digits away, while another `,` should be 2 digits away from the previous `,`?

Comment: errr... the number `1250845` is one million two hundred and fifty thousand eight hundred and forty five so the `number_format` is correct

Comment: I didn't notice the use of the precision `2` in the `round` ~ I looked closer and saw my mistook so deleted the comment - however, it is redundant in this case anyway if you then use the same precision in the number_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
function formatInIndianStyle($num)
{
    // This is my function
    $pos = strpos((string) $num, ".");
    if ($pos === false)
    {
        $decimalpart = "00";
    }
    else
    {
        $decimalpart = substr($num, $pos + 1, 2);
        $num = substr($num, 0, $pos);
    }

    if (strlen($num) > 3 & strlen($num) <= 12)
    {
        $last3digits = substr($num, -3);
        $numexceptlastdigits = substr($num, 0, -3);
        $formatted = makecomma($numexceptlastdigits);
        $stringtoreturn = $formatted . "," . $last3digits . "." . $decimalpart;
    }
    elseif (strlen($num) <= 3)
    {
        $stringtoreturn = $num . "." . $decimalpart;
    }
    elseif (strlen($num) > 12)
    {
        $stringtoreturn = number_format($num, 2);
    }

    if (substr($stringtoreturn, 0, 2) == "-,")
    {
        $stringtoreturn = "-" . substr($stringtoreturn, 2);
    }

    return $stringtoreturn;
}

function makecomma($input)
{
    // This function is written by some anonymous person - I got it from Google
    if (strlen($input) <= 2)
    {
        return $input;
    }
    $length = substr($input, 0, strlen($input) - 2);
    $formatted_input = makecomma($length) . "," . substr($input, -2);
    return $formatted_input;
}

$a = 1095362.2362548;
$b = 155482.94974120325;
$result = $a + $b;

echo formatInIndianStyle($result);
```

This will output as `12,50,845.18`.

Note: You can get the above method from here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#40558

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function for rather then number_format(), its working same as number_format also you can customized in it.

```
<?php 

function my_number_format($number, $dec_point, $thousands_sep) 
{ 
    $was_neg = $number < 0; // Because +0 == -0 
    $number = abs($number); 

    $tmp = explode('.', $number); 
    $out = number_format($tmp[0], 0, $dec_point, $thousands_sep); 
    if (isset($tmp[1])) $out .= $dec_point.$tmp[1]; 

    if ($was_neg) $out = "-$out"; 

    return $out; 
} 

$a = 1095362.2362548;

$b =155482.94974120325;

$result = $a + $b;

echo my_number_format(round($result,2),'.',',');

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For that, use the build in [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) function. Should do the job.